# Как предоставляют платные курсы для скачивания?

Tags: php

Допустим человек купил курс, появилась ссылка для скачивания, он нажал скачать...
1. Если сделать, что на ссылку можно нажать только 1 раз, а если человек не докачал файл (пропал интернет или еще что-то).
2. Если сделать временную ссылку (скажем на 1 час), то он может выложить ее и смогут скачивать все...
Вообщем как это правильно реализуется?

Comment: Ну никто же не запрещает дать ссылку на час но с учетом ip или высылать ссылку на почту и привязывать её на час но к email.... то есть дополнительно что-то привязать, что может идентифицировать конкретного пользователя

Comment: о как вариант, посмотреть заголовоки с какой почты пришел пользователь и сохранить, а потом эти данные сверять.... я понял..

Comment: Даже не так.. надо наоборот.... вы сохраняете в БД хэш и к какому email пользователя он относится...... скачивать могут только зареганные пользователи.... и если ссылку открыл гость (не зареганный) или пользователь, но не с тем идентификатором - то кукиш ему.........как минимум выставляя то, что качать может только зарегистрированные - вы уже часть отсекаете....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы скачать

1. человек должен быть авторизован на сайте;
2. ему проставляется куки;
3. ссылка живёт ограниченное время.

При запросе по ссылке проверяется валидность ссылки и наличие куки.

Что не отменяет вероятность того, что скачанный файл тут же загрузят на торрент-трекер. Поэтому для пущей защиты можно проставлять watermark'ом на видео уникальный номер клиента, чтобы знать, кому потом писать гневные email'ы, которые тот проигнорирует : )

---

P.s. в одном проекте я сделал раздачу видео потоком [RTMP через амазоновский CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html) – тоже создавались временные ссылки для просмотра, кук не было, видео отдавалось потоком, и его относительно трудно сохранить, по сравнению с отдачей файлов.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте авторизацию пользователей, записывайте в определенную таблицу покупок и храните в этой таблице поле, какую книгу купили и идентификатор пользователя. При возвращении пользователя на страницу покупок (пользователя) он сможет увидеть что купил и повторно скачать.